# Is there any way to define an environment variable that is accessible across all stages of the IBM Bluemix DevOps Build pipeline

Tags: ibm-cloud, build-process, devops, build-pipeline

Would anyone know if there is any magic way to define an env variable that could be accessed from all stages of the DevOps build pipeline?

So far, it seems the only thing you can do is to define env variables shared by all jobs inside the same stage.

I understand that each stage run in complete isolation under the cover, but still I was wondering if any trick could be done to define a common env variable for all stages?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Environment variables are per stage.  There is currently no way to have the same environment variable across that entire pipeline.  You would need to set it on each stage individually.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying

Answer (score 1):

Environment variables are per stage, correct, so if you want one to exist across all stages in a pipeline, you'll need to add it to each stage.

For a list of built-in environment variables and other information, take a look at this documentation page: https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/DeliveryPipeline/deploy_var.html

Comment: Thank you for clarifying